# Wake up by push notification receive messages and send delivery while in background

Tags: android, quickblox

Using the **quickblox** API, what is the correct strategy to receive messages (after receiving push notification) while the app is in background?

This is my approach (but it is not working properly):
After receiving a push notification in `GCMIntentService` I am using `QBChatService` to login (after creating the session and user sign In).
Then using `QBChatService.getDialogMessages()` I retrieve the message and save in the database. Finally I logout from the chat service and destroy it.

The point is before and as well as the app goes to background it receives the messages as expected. But when it comes to foreground again it does not receive the messages any more.
If I comment `updateDialog(dialogId)` (see the code snippet below) which means no message retrieval while in background after push notification, then everything works as expected.
Note: whenever the app goes in background it logs out and when comes to foreground does login again.

It seems the problem is logging in using `QBChatService` in `loadDialogMessages` method.

I use Quickblox 2.0 api and Q-municate as my base code.
The implementation in Q-municate is this way: when the app goes to background (and logs out) it simply notifies user for a new message. If user brings the app to foreground, then the app retrieves the new messages. But I want to retrieve messages (after receiving push notification) and save locally even before the user brings the app to foreground.

Any idea how to resolve this?

Here is part of the code I use:

```
//GCMIntentService.java

protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    ...
    if(isAppRunning()) {
        // ignore
    }else{
        updateDialog(dialogId); //Retrieves messages synchronously from server, saves in data base and sends delivery notice
        sendNotification(); // notifies user 
    }
    ...
}

public void updateDialog(String dialogId)
        throws BaseServiceException, SmackException, XMPPException, IOException {
    QBDialog dialog = DatabaseManager.getDialogByDialogId(context, dialogId);

    MessageCache lastMessage = DatabaseManager.getLastMessage(context, dialog);
    if (lastMessage == null) {
        loadDialogMessages(dialog, 0L);
    } else {
        long lastMessageDateSent = lastMessage.getTime();
        loadDialogMessages(dialog, lastMessageDateSent);
    }
}

public void  loadDialogMessages(QBDialog dialog, long lastDateLoad)
        throws IOException, BaseServiceException, XMPPException, SmackException {
    if(!QBChatService.isInitialized()) {
        QBChatService.init(context);
    }
    QBChatService chatService = QBChatService.getInstance();
    if(!chatService.isLoggedIn()) {
        chatService.login(login()); // login() method creates session and signes in the user
    }
    chatService.stopAutoSendPresence();

    if (lastDateLoad != 0L) {
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        QBCustomObjectRequestBuilder customObjectRequestBuilder = new QBCustomObjectRequestBuilder();
        customObjectRequestBuilder.setPagesLimit(Consts.DIALOG_MESSAGES_PER_PAGE);
        customObjectRequestBuilder.gt(com.quickblox.internal.module.chat.Consts.MESSAGE_DATE_SENT,
                lastDateLoad);
        List<QBChatHistoryMessage> dialogMessagesList = QBChatService.getDialogMessages(dialog, customObjectRequestBuilder, bundle);

        if (dialogMessagesList != null) {
            saveChatMessagesAndSendDelivery(chatService, dialogMessagesList, dialog.getDialogId());
        }
    }

    chatService.logout();
    chatService.destroy();
}
```

Comment: wait a minute why do you log out? aren't you pose to like keep your chart session is a service class and keep retrieving messages, idk your way, but just my concerns

Comment: If I don't log out then it keeps the network active, which leads to battery drain. So the idea is: no network activity until a notification is received, then login-retrieve-logout (again no netwrok activity any more to avoid battery drain).